# How to be a bit more efficient with Sapper?

Tags: javascript, structure, svelte

Currently using Sapper to create a design system app.

I have a heirachy of folders which create the app through the routes folder.

The folder structure looks something like this:

```
design-foundations
- interactions
-- buttons
-- inputs
- components
-- header
```

Here is a look at my `design-foundations/interactions/buttons.html`:

```
<Layout>
    <h1>Buttons</h1>
</Layout>

<script>
    import Layout from '../../_components/helpers/Layout.html';

    export default {
        components: {
            Layout
        }
    };
</script>
```

If you were to open up my `design-foundations/interactions/inputs.html` file, or any of the other files under `design-foundations`, you will see a file which looks very much the same, where the bottom part of the file exports the `Layout` component.

Is there some way I can avoid this code duplication in my files?

I would really like to somehow avoid the  tag at the end of each of these files if somehow possible.

Comment: although I haven't used sapper or svelte. I think you add the script tag there so you can do all the component code in one file. in the compile step it replaces that tag. Sometimes you can't get rid of basic duplication but they may offer auto generation of that code through their cli

Comment: There are standard components available such as <:Head>. I wonder if there is a way to make one of my components a "global" component so that I can use it with the colon operator?

Comment: I don't see an api for that in the docs but you might get a better answer to this by asking in their chat / gitter: https://gitter.im/sveltejs/svelte

Comment: currently there are a discussion for this, [Reduce boilerplate when importing components](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1038) I hope it is available in the next versions

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are after, but you no longer need to load the layout into your component, rather the component is now loaded in the layout. Upgrade to the latest version of Sapper and you will see the directory structure changes along with the new App.html that you need to add in your code.